# Hana Cloud, issue with stored procedure WITH RESULT VIEW

Tags: hana

I would like to create stored procedure in Hana Cloud with option "WITH RESULT VIEW". Unfortunately , it generates an error and different adjustments (delete second output parameter, etc) doesn't help.

I appreciate if somebody suggests the root cause of the error. See the screenshot [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnK2e.jpg)

Thanks

second output parameter removed

view name changed

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WITH RESULT VIEW` is not available on SAP HANA Cloud. Check the [documentation](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-sqlscript-reference/create-procedure) of `CREATE PROCEDURE` or the [list of SQL/SQLScript incompatibilities](https://help.sap.com/docs/hana-cloud-database/sap-hana-cloud-sap-hana-database-sql-reference-guide/sql-and-sqlscript-compatibility) between SAP HANA 2 and SAP HANA Cloud for more details.